# How to create Sidebar menu from list menu

Tags: javascript, css, menu, sidebar, bootstrap-vue

I'm actually creating a website based on Vue.js(v2) and bootstrap-vue. I would like to make a responsive menu that hides into a sidebar. The question is how can I make the sidebar from the menu list ?
What, if any, can be reworked to have an effect like in the pictures ?
What am I doing wrong?
I will be very grateful for any advice/answer
This is my first post so please be understanding :)
[List-menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtUsj.png)
,
[effect like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egw1r.png)

```
<template>
  <aside class="left-menu p-3">
    <ul class="left-menu__list">
      <li class="left-menu__list__link"><a href="#">Article 1</a></li>
      <li class="left-menu__list__link"><a href="#">Article 2</a></li>
      <li class="left-menu__list__link"><a href="#">Article 3</a></li>
      <li class="left-menu__list__link"><a href="#">Article 4</a></li>
      <li class="left-menu__list__link"><a href="#">Article 5</a></li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
</template>

<script>
export default {};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
.left-menu {
  width: 20%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
.left-menu__list {
  width: 100%;
  list-style-type: none;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.left-menu__list__link {
  padding: 5px 0;
}
.left-menu__list__link a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #b3bcc3;
  &:hover {
    color: #fff;
  }
}
</style>
```

I'm currently looking at tutorials and they all only deal with navigation bar on dropdown.